# always getting OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired

Tags: android, pushsharp

i am always getting `OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired` on server when sending push to GCM
i have even tried to unregister from my android app

i always get the same registration id in my Android app

```
push.RegisterGcmService(New GcmPushChannelSettings("AI45747erhgedhe4ag"))

Dim and_msg() As String = message.Split(New Char() {":"c}, 2)

push.QueueNotification(New GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(q.PushToken.Token).WithJson("{""title"": """ & and_msg(0) & """,""message"": """ & and_msg(1) & """, ""sound"": true,""vibrate"": true}"))

push.StopAllServices(True)
```